# Scrolling fixed sidebar then unfix after scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, user-interface

I'm trying to mimic a feature of this site: https://johnkingforgovernor.com/home.html

If you scroll down, there is a box on the right that follow you down the page until it reaches the footer. So it's like some sort logic that sets a window for which the side bar is fixed. Here is my code.

```
    var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
    var distanceFromTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    jQuery(window).on("scroll", function(event){
        windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
        distanceFromTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        

        if (distanceFromTop > jQuery("#firstdiv").height() && distanceFromTop < jQuery("#seconddiv").height()) {
          // Lock
        } else {
          // Unlock
        }
    });
```

Comment: They have a `contentright` div container to which they append the class `fixed` or `fixedBottom` depending on the position of the scroll. They basically are swapping between `position: absolute;` and `position: fixed;` in their CSS. I guess that's what you want to do in your lock/unlock blocks. Also, any particular reason why you're using jquery here? Just curious.

Comment: @EdgardoRodríguez what should I be using instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of sticky along with an IntersectionObserver to achieve this which saves having to constantly look for whether the user is scrolling and making adjustments.

The fixed/floating box is set initially to sticky which means as you scroll down it will stick to the top of the viewport when it's there. Then an intersection observer on the footer causes the box to be set to relative ('unsticks it') so it will move up as the footer is more fully revealed. When the footer is scrolled out of sight, the box reverts to being sticky.

Here's a simple set-up to demonstrate:

```js
function observed(entries) {
 if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
   box.style.position = 'relative';
   box.style.top = 'calc(' + footer.offsetTop + 'px - 100vh - ' + box.parentElement.offsetTop + 'px)';
 }
 else {
   box.style.position = 'sticky';
   box.style.top = '0px';
 }
}
const box=document.querySelector('#box');
const footer = document.querySelector('footer');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(observed);

observer.observe(footer);
```

```css
header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 30vh;
  background: cyan;
}
.content {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 200vh;
  position: relative;
}


#box {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: pink;
  width: 20vw;
  height:10vw;
}

footer {
  height: 50vh;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<header>HEADER</header>
<div class="content">
  <div id="box">FLOATING/FIXED BOX</div>
</div>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```